# JavaScript Sharpen Image and Edge Detection not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filter, pixel

I made a simple web application of Image Manipulation/filters with HTML5 and JavaScript. Every filters are working fine like Brightness, Grayscale, Negative etc. Except Sharpen Image, Edge-detection all kinds of Neighbourhood operation are not working.

I have tried every possible way, tried to google, looked for references but failed. The references that I found shows the Matrix system, I know the concept of the Matrix System, but don't know how to apply. It would be kind if I can get a solution of my problem. Please see my codes below, for the time being, I am posting my Sharp an image codes.

I Found Something like this to sharp an Image
( [  0, -1,  0,
    -1,  5, -1,
     0, -1,  0 ]), but how to apply I dont know. So I tried to apply it like the codes below

```
<script>
function pic() {
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var btnsharpen = document.getElementById('btnsharpen');
var img = new Image();

            img.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }

//sharp the image
btnsharpen.onclick = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, c.width, c.height);

        var pixels = imgData.data;
        var numPixels = ((imgData.width-1) *(imgData*4)+ ((imgData.height)*4)); 
        for (var i = 0, n = numPixels; i < n; i +=4) {
            var sharpen = (pixels[i] * 0 + pixels[i + 1] * 0 + pixels[i + 2] * 0) +
              (pixels[i] * -1 + pixels[i + 1] * -1 + pixels[i + 2] * -1) +
              (pixels[i] * 0 + pixels[i + 1] * 0 + pixels[i + 2] * 0) +
              (pixels[i] * -1 + pixels[i + 1] * -1 + pixels[i + 2] * -1) +
              (pixels[i] * 5 + pixels[i + 1] * 5 + pixels[i + 2] * 5) +
              (pixels[i] * -1 + pixels[i + 1] * -1 + pixels[i + 2] * -1) +
              (pixels[i] * 0 + pixels[i + 1] * 0 + pixels[i + 2] * 0) +
              (pixels[i] * -1 + pixels[i + 1] * -1 + pixels[i + 2] * -1) +
              (pixels[i] * 0 + pixels[i + 1] * 0 + pixels[i + 2] * 0);

            pixels[i] = sharpen; // red
            pixels[i + 1] = sharpen; // green
            pixels[i + 2] = sharpen; // blue
            }

            ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
            img.src = "image/Angelina_Jolie.jpg";
        }
</script>

<body onLoad="pic()">
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='500' height='375' style='border:solid 1px #000000'></canvas>
<input type="button" value="Sharpen" class="buttons" id="btnsharpen" /><br />
</body>
```

Comment: did you search for javascript libs or C libs doing just that ?

Comment: no @GameAlchemist I havent searched.... I am really having a headache with this problem

Comment: Have a look here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

Comment: I tried that couple of times, but not working, I know the concept of the 3x3 matrix of convolution, but I dont know how to apply it in codes... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question (hopefully you found your answer, @bleach64), but for anyone that's interested, here's a fiddle for image sharpening that I found:

[Step-down downsample + sharpen convolution](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ddJZB/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    offScreen = document.createElement('canvas'),
    offctx = offScreen.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image();

/// as we need pixel access to apply convolution we
/// need to get around CORS:
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

/// when image is loaded step-down the downscaling
img.onload = resize;
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/DR94LKg.jpg";

/// sharpen image:
/// USAGE:
///    sharpen(context, width, height, mixFactor)
///  mixFactor: [0.0, 1.0]
function sharpen(ctx, w, h, mix) {

    var weights = [0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0],
        katet = Math.round(Math.sqrt(weights.length)),
        half = (katet * 0.5) | 0,
        dstData = ctx.createImageData(w, h),
        dstBuff = dstData.data,
        srcBuff = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data,
        y = h;

    while (y--) {

        x = w;

        while (x--) {

            var sy = y,
                sx = x,
                dstOff = (y * w + x) * 4,
                r = 0,
                g = 0,
                b = 0,
                a = 0;

            for (var cy = 0; cy < katet; cy++) {
                for (var cx = 0; cx < katet; cx++) {

                    var scy = sy + cy - half;
                    var scx = sx + cx - half;

                    if (scy >= 0 && scy < h && scx >= 0 && scx < w) {

                        var srcOff = (scy * w + scx) * 4;
                        var wt = weights[cy * katet + cx];

                        r += srcBuff[srcOff] * wt;
                        g += srcBuff[srcOff + 1] * wt;
                        b += srcBuff[srcOff + 2] * wt;
                        a += srcBuff[srcOff + 3] * wt;
                    }
                }
            }

            dstBuff[dstOff] = r * mix + srcBuff[dstOff] * (1 - mix);
            dstBuff[dstOff + 1] = g * mix + srcBuff[dstOff + 1] * (1 - mix);
            dstBuff[dstOff + 2] = b * mix + srcBuff[dstOff + 2] * (1 - mix)
            dstBuff[dstOff + 3] = srcBuff[dstOff + 3];
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(dstData, 0, 0);
}

/// naive and non-efficient implementation of update, but
/// do illustrate the impact of sharpen after a downsample
function resize() {

    /// set canvas size proportional to original image
    canvas.height = canvas.width * (img.height / img.width);

    /// set off-screen canvas/sharpening source to same size
    offScreen.width = canvas.width;
    offScreen.height = canvas.height;

    /// step 1 in down-scaling
    var oc = document.createElement('canvas'),
        octx = oc.getContext('2d');

    oc.width = img.width * 0.5;
    oc.height = img.height * 0.5;
    octx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

    /// step 2
    octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5);

    /// draw final result to screen canvas
    ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5,
    0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    /// copy to off-screen to use as source for shapening
    offctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

    /// apply sharpening convolution
    update();
}

/// adjustable sharpening - update cached source
function update() {
    ctx.drawImage(offScreen, 0, 0);
    sharpen(ctx, canvas.width, canvas.height, parseInt(mix.value) * 0.01);
}
```